# Remove part of string in text box

Tags: jquery

I have several text boxes with class name 'check'. It already has '12/12/2001 00:00:00' string. I want to remove the '00:00:00' part from every text boxes. How do I do this from jquery?

Comment: I'm from the C# stack. There might be also something like a `DataFormatString`.

Comment: I tried but didn't remove that part. No errors even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the value and truncate it at the first space.

```
$("input.check").each(function() {
    var index = this.value.indexOf(" ");
    if (index >= 0) {
        this.value = this.value.substring(0, index);
    }
});
```

You can do it with a shorter bit of code using `split`, but it works harder:

```
$("input.check").each(function() {
    this.value = this.value.split(' ')[0];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
$('input.check').each( function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    var value = elem.val().split(' ')[0];
    elem.val(value);
});
```

Comment: There's exactly zero reason to wrap up the DOM element in a jQuery wrapper (`value` is completely reliable on `input` elements), but *if* you're going to, at least only do it *once*? ;-)

Comment: I used this. working. but finally I used T.J. Crowder's answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, thanks. I was originally writing it as a one-liner; by the time it started looking too long, I just split it into two lines and overlooked the two `$(this)` expressions. Cheers <3

Answer (score 0):

Dont have idea about your server side code, you might do like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.check').each(function () {

            $(this).val($(this).val.replace(" 00:00:00",""));

    }) });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Jquery/Javascript**

```
var val = $(".check").val();
$(".check").val(val.substring(1, val.indexOf("00:00:00")-1));
```

**HTML**

```
<input class="check" value="12/12/2001 00:00:00"/>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/VkcFm/

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.check').each(function(i){
  var checkValue= $(this).val();
  checkValue.replace('00:00:00','');
  $(this).val(checkValue);
});
```

Try this code

Comment: ...and actually _setting_ the value of the field?

Comment: You've fixed **half** of the bugs reported above.

Comment: which part of the bug is remaining